# can we able to lock all applications in android device through android-management-api?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-applicationinfo, application-blocks

While applying lock command through android-management-api in the device, the device will be locked. But if users know the password, they can able to unlock the device and use the applications in the device.

My requirement is to disable all applications for a specific amount of time. Is there any possibility to achieve this functionality through android-management-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to lock the device and prevent user access entirely, you can reset the device’s password and then lock the device using [issueCommand](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand): RESET_PASSWORD and LOCK.

You can also use [Devices.patch()](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/patch) and set state to “DISABLED” to disable all the applications (for fully managed devices) or  work apps (when enrolled in work profile) from the device.

If perhaps you want to achieve this because of compliance issues, then the IT admin can wipe the device (for fully managed), remove any corporate apps from the device, or remove the work profile. This can also be automated by using [compliance rules](https://developers.google.com/android/management/compliance).

Comment: It is working for all other apps except in-built apps of google. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: What is working with all other apps? Is it the state: "DISABLED"? Also, can you provide these in-built apps for Google?

Comment: Default applications like google,contacts,phone and settings

Comment: Those applications are system applications and it is working as intended that those applications will not be disabled upon setting the state to DISABLED.

Comment: @DavePaurillo Can we disable specific apps if installed for fully controlled devices?

Answer (score 0):

use disable key word and set as true in application policy to disable the app.

Try this link.

And also vote me if it works fine.
https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#applicationpolicy